# Group By multple columns with conditions Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Can anyone shed some lights to how I should tackle this problem.

Current data

| Name | Code | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1A | 2020-05-03 | 34 |
| A | 1A | 2020-04-02 | 25 |
| B | 3D | 2021-04-23 | 24 |
| C | 2X | 2021-04-01 | 01 |
| C | 2X | 2021-03-31 | 01 |

Desired Output:

| Name | Code | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1A | 2020-05-03 | 34 |
| B | 3D | 2021-04-23 | 24 |
| C | 2X | 2021-04-01 | 01 |
| C | 2X | 2021-03-31 | 01 |

Output from my code:

| Name | Code | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1A | 2020-05-03 | 34 |
| B | 3D | 2021-04-23 | 24 |
| C | 2X | 2021-04-01 | 01 |

Below is my code:

```html
SELECT 
  name, 
  code, 
  MAX(date) AS dates, 
  MAX(Cases_Number) AS Max_Num 
FROM(
  SELECT 
    lhd_2010_name AS name, 
     lhd_2010_code AS code, 
     notification_date AS date, 
     FLOOR(SUM(num)) as Cases_Number 
  FROM cases 
  GROUP BY 
    notification_date, 
    lhd_2010_name,
    lhd_2010_code 
  ORDER BY Cases_Number DESC, notification_date, lhd_2010_name DESC
) AS innertable 
  
GROUP BY name,code ORDER BY Max_Num DESC")
```

In the innertable I had to sum up the counts as all the counts were 1 before with GroupBy Name Code and Date to get the total counts.  Then on the outertable I have to find the max count based on Name+Code combination.  If max count is the same name+code combination, we will output the row too.

I understand the reason for the missing row is because I have used max(date), but this is the only way for me to be able to group by name and code, and also showing the dates.  If I try to group by name, code, and dates it will show all other rows.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Some parts are missing for us to understand well your question. 1. A dataset sample of the starting data (dump it as text, it's easier to read than jpeg), 2. an example of what is missing / not taken into account.

Comment: Hi marc, thanks for the feedback, have edited the question.  Hopefully it is better now

Comment: What's a `SELECT name, code, date, MAX(Cases_Number) AS Max_Num FROM(...) AS innertable GROUP BY name,code,date ORDER BY Max_Num DESC")` would do? If I remove the `max(date)` in the select and return it to `date` and add this `date` also, in the final `GROUP BY` clause? Can you try it?

Comment: this would pretty much give me the current data back out as it takes a unique combination of name,code and date in the GROUP BY, so 
A  1A  2020-04-02  25
will be in the output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your main table `main`, we can first group by `name`, `code` and `count` to find the count (of duplicates), we name the alias `countDup` and we filter `countDup` > 1, basically, we need these kind of rows:

```
|C   |2X  |1    |2020-04-01|
```

The code looks like this:

```
val ds2 = main.groupBy("name", "code", "count")
  .agg(count("*").alias("countDup"))
  .where(col("countDup")
  .gt(1))
```

Preview of the code:

```
+----+----+-----+--------+
|name|code|count|countDup|
+----+----+-----+--------+
|   C|  2X|    1|       2|
+----+----+-----+--------+
```

Then, we join with main table (left join), we add a rank to get maximum count, then we use a filter to filter only rows that we want, code:

```
main
  .join(ds2, Seq("name", "code", "count"), "left")
  .withColumn("ranking", expr("max(count) over (partition by name,code)"))
  .filter(col("countDup").isNotNull || col("count").equalTo(col("ranking")))
  .drop("countDup", "ranking")
  .orderBy("name")
```

Final output (with order in `name`):

```
+----+----+-----+----------+
|name|code|count|date      |
+----+----+-----+----------+
|A   |1A  |34   |2020-05-03|
|B   |3D  |24   |2020-04-23|
|C   |2X  |1    |2020-04-01|
|C   |2X  |1    |2020-03-31|
+----+----+-----+----------+
```

I hope this is what you need!

**SPARK SQL VERSION**

First, we create the temp table:

```
main.createTempView("main")
```

Then apply the following SQL:

```
SELECT name,code,date,count FROM (
    SELECT m.name,m.code,m.date,m.count,r.countDup,MAX(m.count) OVER (PARTITION BY m.name,m.code) AS ranking FROM main m LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT name,code,count,COUNT(*) AS countDup FROM main GROUP BY name,code,count HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) r 
    ON m.name = r.name AND m.code = r.code AND m.count = r.count) 
WHERE countDup > 0 OR count == ranking ORDER BY name
```

Result is the same as above!

Comment: thanks sofizh, any chance this can be put into SQL codes like what I wrote on the question?

Comment: translated that to SQL, edited the comment, good luck!

Comment: No problem, please mark the problem as solved for people with similar issue